# Magento2: Issues after switch to production mode

Tags: magento2

We have issues after switch to production mode:
no work any style css: Gerris.pl

Answer (score 1):

You have to deploy the static content and recompile the code and clear all caches after switching the mode.

So you may have to run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

When you switch to production mode, Magento clear the contents of following directories:

```
var/cache
var/di
var/generation
var/view_preprocessed
pub/static
```

Now you have to deploy the `static-content` like this:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Clear content from directory var are:

```
var/cache
var/di
var/generation
var/view_processed
```

2.Clear content from pub directory except .htaccess file.

3.Now run command forcefully because in production mode content not automatically deploy like developer mode so here we need to use -f after command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```